# How to call customer account sidebar on custom magento extension

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

I am developing a magento extension in which i need to call the customer account side bar in the left section on my extension template i have tried adding it to my extension  layout xml but with no luck :'( any body had any previous experience with this please share.

**Note : I am using Magento ver. 1.7.0.2**

Comment: Can you perhaps post the XML snippet that you used?

Comment: i have tried adding <reference name="left"></reference> under my extension XML, It seems i must doing it wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure, what you want. As @SanderMangel understands it, you want to add links to the customer menu, is this right?

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt i want to show to customer account side bar in my extension left bar.

Comment: Then Marius has the answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can tell your layout handle to use the customer_account handle

```
<custom_layout_handle>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <!-- additional statements here --> 
</custom_layout_handle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the following to your XML?

```
<reference name="left">
    [...]
    <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
    </block>
    [...]
</reference>
```