# Adding Customer Account Navigation in my custom extension

Tags: magento-1.8, blocks, navigation, customer-account

In my extension, I have created a page for the logged in users. but the current template only shows my content and other sidebar widgets like "My Wishlist", "My Cart", etc. But I also need to display the **customer_account_navigation** on the top of sidebar similar to other customer pages.

What I have in my controller is

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->renderLayout();
```

My layout is

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="myext">
            <name>myext</name>
            <path>myext/</path>
            <label>My Extension</label>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
<update handle="customer_account"/>
<routeurfrontend_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="myext/myblock"  name="list_myblock"
                      template="myext/list.phtml" />
    </reference>
</routeurfrontend_index_index>
```

have added `<update handle="customer_account"/>` in reference to the question [How to call customer account sidebar on custom magento extension](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/2944/how-to-call-customer-account-sidebar-on-custom-magento-extension), but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<routeurfrontend_index_index>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="myext/myblock"  name="list_myblock" template="myext/list.phtml" />
    </reference>
</routeurfrontend_index_index>
```

**FYI :** Refer core files for any reference. i have refer this code in `newsletter.xml` file